# Bitwise and MySQL for Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, bit-manipulation

I have a table with a field name `department`, this field contains bitwise values.

I want to check if the department field is inside the departments allowed to access by the user. But doing the following doesn't work:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('department & ' => $this->Session->read('User.departments')),
    'limit'      => 10,
    'order'      => 'date DESC',
);
```

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is incorrect. See [Mysql Bitwise operations and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637922/mysql-bitwise-operations-and-filter)

Try this:

```
'conditions' => array(
   "ModelName.department & '" . $this->Session->read('User.departments') . "'"
)
```

Comment: The result (fail) is: SELECT `Work`.`id`, `Work`.`user_id`, `Work`.`department`, `Work`.`license_plate`, `Work`.`chassis_number`, `Work`.`comission_number`, `Work`.`programs`, `Work`.`specials`, `Work`.`regie`, `Work`.`comments`, `Work`.`total`, `Work`.`date`, `Work`.`picture` FROM `carwash`.`works` AS `Work` WHERE .department & '3' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: The issue is you're not doing that in a model, that's why $this->alias is not available. You should move the whole code into a model method and pass the session id to it. Would you mind flagging the answer as correct please?

Comment: With this it works fine: 'conditions' => array("department & '" . $this->Session->read('User.departments') . "'"),